# Install error on Wordpress with Smarty.class.php

Tags: wordpress, installation, smarty

I have installed CIVI-5.41.0 for WordPress version 5.8.1, updated all the permission as well as php version 8 but still keep getting this error.

Warning: Smarty error: problem creating directory 'D:/HostingSpaces' in D:\HostingSpaces\tester\testingtesting123.uk\public_html\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\packages\Smarty\Smarty.class.php on line 1100

Warning: include(D:\HostingSpaces\tester\testingtesting123.uk\public_html/wp-content/uploads\civicrm\templates_c\en_US\%%E6\E65\E656EDCD%%wordpress.tpl.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\HostingSpaces\tester\testingtesting123.uk\public_html\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\packages\Smarty\Smarty.class.php on line 1273

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'D:\HostingSpaces\tester\testingtesting123.uk\public_html/wp-content/uploads\civicrm\templates_c\en_US\%%E6\E65\E656EDCD%%wordpress.tpl.php' for inclusion (include_path='D:\HostingSpaces\tester\testingtesting123.uk\public_html\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\ext\legacycustomsearches;D:\HostingSpaces\tester\testingtesting123.uk\public_html\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\ext\ckeditor4;D:\HostingSpaces\tester\testingtesting123.uk\public_html\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\ext\recaptcha;D:\HostingSpaces\tester\testingtesting123.uk\public_html\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\ext\financialacls;D:\HostingSpaces\tester\testingtesting123.uk\public_html\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\ext\eventcart;D:\HostingSpaces\tester\testingtesting123.uk\public_html\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\ext\greenwich;.;D:\HostingSpaces\tester\testingtesting123.uk\public_html\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm;D:\HostingSpaces\tester\testingtesting123.uk\public_html\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\packages;D:\HostingSpaces\tester\testingtesting123.uk\public_html\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\vendor/tecnickcom;D:\HostingSpaces\tester\testingtesting123.uk\public_html\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\vendor/pear/pear_exception;D:\HostingSpaces\tester\testingtesting123.uk\public_html\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\vendor/pear/auth_sasl;D:\HostingSpaces\tester\testingtesting123.uk\public_html\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\vendor/pear/console_getopt;D:\HostingSpaces\tester\testingtesting123.uk\public_html\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src;D:\HostingSpaces\tester\testingtesting123.uk\public_html\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\vendor/pear/db;D:\HostingSpaces\tester\testingtesting123.uk\public_html\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\vendor/pear/log;D:\HostingSpaces\tester\testingtesting123.uk\public_html\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\vendor/pear/mail;D:\HostingSpaces\tester\testingtesting123.uk\public_html\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\vendor/pear/mail_mime;D:\HostingSpaces\tester\testingtesting123.uk\public_html\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\vendor/pear/net_socket;D:\HostingSpaces\tester\testingtesting123.uk\public_html\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\vendor/pear/net_smtp;D:\HostingSpaces\tester\testingtesting123.uk\public_html\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\vendor/pear/validate_finance_creditcard;.;D:\HostingSpaces\tester\testingtesting123.uk\public_html\wp-content\plugins\civicrm/civicrm;D:\HostingSpaces\tester\testingtesting123.uk\public_html\wp-content\plugins\civicrm/civicrm\packages;C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\vendor') in D:\HostingSpaces\tester\testingtesting123.uk\public_html\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\packages\Smarty\Smarty.class.php on line 1273

Please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SE!  Very few people run CiviCRM on Windows.  You will find far more support if you run it on Linux.  If you're new to Civi you might want to look https://civicrm.org/spark where the installation is taken care of and you can quickly get to using Civi.

Comment: Thank you.  Ah I see what the problem is I think, but don't know how to fix it! the file path has added the database username and therefore that directory doesn't exist. where would I edit how the file path is created?